# Webpack 5 Asset modules not creating images to dist folder when using handlebars-loader. How do i get it to output the images?

Tags: webpack, handlebars.js, m, webpack-html-loader

This is my config file, I have tried with html-loader it works fine for .html files but i’m now trying to learn and use handlebarsjs its not working the same. I've also tried using the preprocessor option for html-loader whereby i created a function to read .hbs files but I keep getting errors.

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
    plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Output Management',
            template: './src/index.hbs'
    }),
  ],
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
    static: './dist',
        hot: true,
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath:'/dist/',
        clean:true,
  },
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
            {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
                generator: {
                    filename: 'assets/img/[hash][ext][query]'
                }
      },
            {
        test: /\.hbs$/i,
        use: ['handlebars-loader'],
      },            

    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution should work in Webpack 5:

- in `webpack.config.js`, use `inlineRequires` option for `handlebars-loader`:

```js
{
  test: /\.hbs$/i,
  loader: 'handlebars-loader',
  options: {
    inlineRequires: '\/assets\/img\/'
  }
},
```

- in template files:

```html
<img src="./assets/img/image.png" />
```

From `handlebars-loader` [documentation](https://github.com/pcardune/handlebars-loader#details), the `inlineRequires` option:

> Defines a regex that identifies strings within helper/partial
> parameters that should be replaced by inline require statements.

If you have multiple subfolders in assets (eg: `/img`, `/audio`, `/video`), use the following regex:

```js
inlineRequires: \/assets\/(:?img|audio|video)\/,
```